# Sending Data to SharePoint List From Checkbox HTML Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

I have used a POST before to send list items to SharePoint, although the only items that were included were text inputs so I could call the #id of that input and create the value like so:

```
var item = {
      "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.(ListName)TestListItem" },
      "Title": "No Title",
      "Example": $("#example").val()
};
```

This application, however, is a bit different and I have never used a method like it before. I have about 8 checkbox inputs that I need to concatenate all into one value, to post to my SharePoint list item "Q6", which has all of the same options as multiple choice values.

I will have my fiddle attached, but I cannot log the value that I am trying to use for my "Q6".

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/y463j5gp/4/

Per Ganesh and I's comments, I updated var item to the following and I still get a "Bad Request"

```
var item = {
      "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.FeedbackNewHireTestListItem" },
      "Title": "No Title",
      "_x0051_1": $("#q1").val(),
      "_x0051_2": $("#q2").val(),
      "_x0051_3": $("#q3").val(),
      "_x0051_4": $("#q4").val(),
      "_x0051_5": $("#q5").val(),
      "_x0051_6": {"results": selectedValues},
      "_x0051_7": $("#q7").val(),
      "_x0051_8": $("#q8").val(),
      "_x0051_9": $("#q9").val(),
      "_x0051_10": $("#q10").val(),
      "_x0051_11": $("#q11").val(),
      "_x0051_12": $("#q12").val()
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are already concatenating the values of the checkboxes into a string, and then you are trying to use the jQuery `.val()` function on that string, which you don't need to do.

From your fiddle:

```
var q6 = selectedValues.join(',');
  
console.log(q6); // this outputs a string, so you can see that the selected values appear to be concatenated correctly
```

But then when you are putting together your JSON payload for the SP list item, you have this:

```
// ...
"Q5": $("#q5").val(),
"Q6": $(q6).val(),    // this is not going to work
"Q7": $("#q7").val(),
// ...
```

You already have the value as a string in the `q6` variable, you do not have to "re-`val()`" it to get the value, just use the variable directly:

```
// ...
"Q5": $("#q5").val(),
"Q6": q6,
"Q7": $("#q7").val(),
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save the checkbox selections in **multiple-selection choice field**, you need to pass the data in below format:

```
'Status': { 'results':['Status 1', 'Status 2', 'Status 3'] }
```

So, for your case, try using this:

```
var item = {
      "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.(ListName)TestListItem" },
      "Title": "No Title",
      "Example": { "results": selectedValues }
};
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal name** for `Example` column.

Follow this article to find the internal name of column: [Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Could I do: `"Q6": { "results": q6}`

Comment: It expects array of string. so better try using as given in my answer because you already have array stored in `selectedValues`. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: I tried the selectedValues, and even before you made this answer. With Dylan's answer as well, I keep getting a "Bad Request"

Comment: What is the data type of your column? If choice, is multiple selection enabled for this? What was the exact error message when you tried with `selectedValues`?

Comment: Q6 is a choice column --> Display choices using --> Checkboxes (allow multiple selections). I will add a screenshot to OP

Comment: Ok, with multiple selection choice field, approach given in my answer should work for you? Can you please share the complete error messages while using `selectedValues`?

Comment: I may have just figured something out, for some reason the SharePoint columns when I named them Q6 for example, SharePoint decided to give it this value instead "_x0051_3". Why did it replace my Q character with the _x0051_ for each one?

Comment: That's why I mentioned in my answer to use the correct **internal name** of choice column. Check link in updated answer to find the correct internal name for your choice column.

Comment: I am aware of the internal column name, but I changed my everything in my var item to resemble the internal column names in my list, see most recent edit to OP

Comment: Not sure why SharePoint changes the column name when it starts with `Q`  & 2nd character as number like `Q1`, `Q2`, etc. But I have seen this behavior previously. If you create column with name like `Question1`, `Question2`, etc, It works correctly.

Comment: So is there a way to use the _x0051_ in front of each number instead of creating whole new columns?

Comment: If you are still getting an error, can you please add the error in console using `console.log(error);` & see what is the complete error message? Complete error message will help us to understand the exact issue with POST request.

Comment: when I console.log(error); all it says in console is: Bad Request

Comment: Strange, when you expand error object in console, it should show you the complete error message instead of just Bad request.

Comment: Here it is: 
POST ('FeedbackNewHireTest')/items 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
InsertListItem @ feedbacktest.aspx?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage:697
(anonymous) @ feedbacktest.aspx?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage:663
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: So the things in my script it is referencing are the beginning of my $.ajax, and the InsertListItem(), in my `  $(function () {
      $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
          InsertListItem();
      });
  });
`